# Cannot download RemiRepo for CentOs 8

Tags: php, centos8

I meet the trouble, when i try to install Remi repository for downloading php. When i use command:

```
dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm
```

I have an error:

```
    Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides redhat-release >= 8.6 needed by remi-release-8.6-1.el8.remi.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

What i do wrong? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7):

I did the following to upgrade my CentOS.

```
dnf -y install centos-release-stream
dnf -y swap centos-{linux,stream}-repos
dnf -y distro-sync
```

Answer (score 4):

As explained by the error message, you need CentOS >= 8.6 to take benefit of "remi" repository.

Reminder, CentOS 8 latest version is 8.5, but is no more supported, you have to switch to an alternative:

- CentOS 8 Stream, see [how to switch](https://www.centos.org/centos-stream/)
- RHEL 8 (free subscription available)
- Alma Linux
- Rocky Linux
- or some other RHEL clones

Comment: Hi, I al trying to install remi repo in AlmaLinux 8.6, and have the message `(redhat-release >= 8.8 or centos-stream-release >= 8)`
Do this means that i cannot use remi depot unless I update to Alma Linux 8.8 ?

Comment: I responded myself, by not searching the last release but the one for 8.6: `remi-release-8.6.rpm `

Comment: Please keep in mind using an old version cannot be supported (both by Alma and Remi teams)