# Install Remi repository on CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111 (not CentOS 8 stream)

Tags: centos8, php-8.1

I want to update to PHP 8.1 in my old Centos 8.5.2111 server. But I'm unable to install Remi repository. I get the following:

`othing provides (redhat-release >= 8.7 or centos-stream-release >= 8) needed by remi-release-8.7-2.el8.remi.noarch`

```
[xxxxx@yyyy ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111
[xxxxx@yyyy ~]$ sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm     https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-next-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:36:51 ago on XXX yy Feb 2023 12:07:52 AM CET.
epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm                                                                                              53 kB/s |  24 kB     00:00
epel-next-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm                                                                                         30 kB/s |  11 kB     00:00
Package epel-release-8-18.el8.noarch is already installed.
Package epel-next-release-8-18.el8.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[xxxxx@yyyy ~]$ sudo dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:37:07 ago on XXX yy Feb 2023 12:07:52 AM CET.
remi-release-8.rpm                                                                                                           247 kB/s |  31 kB     00:00
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides (redhat-release >= 8.7 or centos-stream-release >= 8) needed by remi-release-8.7-2.el8.remi.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Maybe I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot download RemiRepo for CentOs 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335143/cannot-download-remirepo-for-centos-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message seems clear.

You need to update to the latest version of the OS, as explained in the [FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#deps). Older versions are insecure and unsupported, and their support in 3rd party repository is not sustainable.

You can choose to switch to

- CentOS Stream 8, see https://www.centos.org/centos-stream/ with migration tools
- RHEL 8.7, see https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/new-year-new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-programs-easier-ways-access-rhel
- Alma Linux 8.7 see https://almalinux.org/ with migration tools
- Rocky Linux 8.7 https://rockylinux.org/ with migration tools
- Any other RHEL clone